# 1.5 billion record insertion into cosmos db using java SDK

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-java-sdk

I have to insert around 1.5 billion records in cosmos db using Java SDK which is broken into batches of 7k documents. I have written the code which generates the data first in the loop then put it into 2 containers, Doucment and Document_attr using `CosmosClient` connection. But it is too slow around 300 items in 1 sec. With this speed, it'll take too long time to get the data into containers. Can someone please suggest the best possible way to achieve insertion of items at faster speed? Throughput is set to auto-scaling and max at `4000RU/s`. Since I'm new to Cosmos DB, I'm unable to optimize the process.

```java
      CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClientBuilder().
            endpoint("<>").key("<>").buildClient();
      CosmosContainer documentContainer = db.getContainer("DOCUMENT");
      CosmosContainer attributeContainer = db.getContainer("DOCUMENT_ATT");
    
      CosmosBulkExecutionOptions bulkExecutionOptions = new CosmosBulkExecutionOptions();
      for(int i=0;i<86400;i++) {
            List<Document> docInsert = new ArrayList<>();
            List<DocumentAttribute> docAttr = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                String docId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                Date expiryTime = DateUtils.addYears(date, 10);

                docInsert.add(new Document(docId, docId, Math.floor(Math.random() * this.maxFileSize) + 1,number));
                docInsert.add(new Document(docId, docId, Math.floor(Math.random() * this.maxFileSize) + 1,number+1));
                number = number + 2 > totalNumber ? 1 : number + 2;
                List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
                users.add(new User(idPrefix+extUserNumber,"EXT",list1));
                users.add(new User(idPrefix+extUserNumber+1,"EXT",list1));
                extUserNumber = extUserNumber + 2 > totalNumber ? 1 : extUserNumber +2;
                for(int u = 0;u<5;u++)
                    users.add(new User(idPrefix+(intNumber+u),"INT",list2));
                intNumber = intNumber + 5 > totalIntNumber ? 1 : intNumber +5;
                docAttr.add(new DocumentAttribute(docId,users date));
            }

            List<CosmosItemOperation> cosmosItemOperationFlux = docInsert.stream().
                    map(doc -> CosmosBulkOperations.getCreateItemOperation(doc,new PartitionKey(doc.getId())))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            documentContainer.executeBulkOperations(cosmosItemOperationFlux, bulkExecutionOptions);
            List<CosmosItemOperation> cosmosItemOperationFlux1 = docAttr.stream().
                    map(doc -> CosmosBulkOperations.getCreateItemOperation(doc,new PartitionKey(doc.getDocId())))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            attributeContainer.executeBulkOperations(cosmosItemOperationFlux1, bulkExecutionOptions);

            date = DateUtils.addSeconds(date, 1);
        }
```

I referred this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/tutorial-dotnet-bulk-import but `CosmosClientOptions` is not available in Java SDK it seems.

Comment: Where is the bottle neck? Are you seeing throttling? 4,000 RU/S seems extremely meagre for this requirement. How much RU is the average insert taking? If it is ~13.33 RU per insert then  300 items in 1 sec is the best you can achieve without either reducing insert cost (e.g. by disabling indexing for the bulk load or at least not using wildcard indexing) or increasing the `RU/s`

Comment: How much storage do you envisage the 1.5 billion records will consume? You should also ensure that you have enough physical partitions up front rather than having partition splits during the operation

Comment: @MartinSmith - I'm expecting ~1400GB of total data and have 5200000 partitions already created for one container. However for the other container, it's created while insertion for uniqueness.

Comment: @MartinSmith -  Not sure how to check RU consumed per insertion but I see throughput for one is 4K and the other is 3.1K. Seems only option here is to increase the RU/s

Comment: You need to look at the "Metrics" for the account in Azure Monitor. "Total Requests" metric filtered on Status = 'ClientThrottlingError' shows how much throttling you are seeing.  "Total Requests" metric with filters for Status = 'success' and OperationType = 'Create' gives you a count of successful inserts and then you can change the metric to "Total Request Units" but keep the filters and time periods the same to see the request units that cost you (and divide one by the other to get an average RU cost per successful create)

Comment: I missed your other comment about 5,200,000 partitions. You certainly don't have that many physical partitions! Each physical partition can support up to 50GB of data - so the minimal number of physical partitions that can support this volume of data is 28. Also you need space used for indexes. If you started off with a single partition then you will probably end up with at least 32 - maybe 64 partitions at the end of this. (so that will be 5 or 6 splits of each partition)

Comment: Are you doing this bulk load into an empty collection? If so I'd probably start again. If you provision an empty collection with 240,000 RU at creation time you will end up with 40 physical partitions with each getting an even split of the partition hash range (as the initial physical partition count at creation time is ceiling(RU/6000), Then you can do the bulk insert and scale it down if you find your application isn't able to keep it fed with enough inserts to max out all the physical partitions.

Comment: Autoscale during the bulk insert seems pointless as ideally you want to be just keeping it maxed out for the duration of the operation - so why pay the 50% premium for this? Once the bulk insert is complete you can set the throughput to your BAU levels

Comment: My script at this stage has inserted ~45million records in last 2 days. Can I increase the throughput of existing containers to 240,000RU/s and keep the same script running?

Comment: For existing containers the logic is different, Each physical partition can support up to 10K RU/S and you will just get partition splits that take you up to `ceiling(RU/10000)` rather than `ceiling(RU/6000)` - so 240,000RU/s  will just give you 24 physical partitions - not 40. If you started off with a single physical partition then 24 physical partitions will mean that some partitions are dealing with twice the key range of others and you should be aiming for 32 or 64. This will take a while though as it will happen through multiple rounds of binary splits rather than in one go

Comment: How many physical partitions is your collection currently using? But anyway to answer your question yes you can do it whilst the insert is still running. You won't actually get access to 240,000 RU until you have at least 24 physical partitions though as each physical partition can only support up to 10K so the available RU for your inserts will increase as and when every partition split happens

Comment: Thanks for the details. Currently, there're 12 partitions(3 and 9 each). With max. partition size in Document being 50.5 GiB and Document_att being 51.1GiB. As 2400000RU/s won't be allowed, increasing it to 120000RU/s for now should be okay to increase bulk loading speed?